# Cast to Array failed for value \"[object Object]\" at path

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mean

I am generator-rest generator of yeoman which is using mongoose, bodymen and express and I have updated the default User schema provided in the generator.

When I send request from Postman I am getting error `Cast to Array failed for value \"[object Object]\" at path \"corp_locations\"`

After Trying all possible ways in multiple posts, I am not able to fix this error.

> Here is my schema

```
const locationsSchema = new Schema({
  location_name: String,
  address: String,
  area: String,
  pincode: Number
})

const userSchema = new Schema({
  user_id: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'User Id is required.'],
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    match: [/^\d{10}$/, 'User Id is invalid.']
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Password is required.'],
    minlength: 6
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    match: [/^\S+@\S+\.\S+$/, 'Email is invalid.'],
    required: [true, 'Email is required.'],
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true
  },
  corp_locations: [locationsSchema],
  created_by: String,
  updated_by: String
}, {
  timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' }
})
```

> The post method

```
router.post('/',
  master(),
  body(schema.tree)
  create)
```

> The create method of controller

```
export const create = ({ bodymen: { body } }, res, next) =>
  User.create(body)
    .then((user) => user.view(true))
    .then(success(res, 201))
    .catch((err) => {

      res.status(409).json(validationMessages(err))
    })
```

> Here is the json sent from Postman

```
{
    "user_id" : "1000000002",
    "password" : "password",
    "email" : "email2@mail.com",
    "corp_locations" : [
        {
            "location_name": "loc1",
            "address": "arrd1",
            "area": "area1",
            "pincode": "9092230"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of google, I found this.

https://github.com/diegohaz/bodymen/issues/1

It was an issue with bodymen and the post method should look like this.

```
router.post('/',
  master(),
  body({user_id, email, password, user_type, corp_locations: [Object]}),
  create)
```

`schema.tree` works fine for simple document but for nested document we have to specify the fields separately, lot of unnecessary code but that is how it works.